# ubuntu 14 glassfish4 shutdown without log

Tags: glassfish-4, ubuntu-14.04

I had install Glassfish 4 on ubuntu 14 server.
After some configurations everything seems to work fine,but sometimes it random shut down
I had install jdk 1.7 60 release but  i don't understand why it die during the night.
I can't figure why jvm or glassfish crash.
A have same problem about crash when chage configuration about jvm in DAS
Can someone help me?
Are there any compatibility issue about this configuration?

Thank in advance

Comment: How much physical memory has the server and how much is the max heap size of the JVM?
I had a crash of GF server, because I had max heap size set to 1024MB, but the virtual server had only 512MB RAM. When fetching some large datastructure into memory, the GF server shut down w/o any log.
You can also try to monitor your GF server with virtualvm. Typically shutdown of GF is an out of memory exception (OOME).

Comment: Thank for reply.I work a lot about this issue.My vm use 6 Gb of ram on VMWare vserver,and i had increase xmx to 3 gb and maxperm to 1 gb.But it crash again.i increased swap space on ubuntu to 8 gb and reduce -Xmx2048m and -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m , and now seem to work fine since 2 days. But jvm.log is very poor log.How can i use virtualvm to monitoring GF server?